# How to Show a View in Sqldeveloper oracle12c

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I would like to show a view in sqldeveloper. How can I do that or is this not possible? Thank you

```
....

create or replace view finalview as
select a,b,c from xxx,yyy;


select * from  finalview;



01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Comment: Presumably the `a, b, c` includes column expresssions, and one of those is converting a string to a number, explicitly or implicitly. Or you have a join condition between `xxx` and `yyy` that is (though you haven't shown that there are any). It's nothing to do with SQL Developer though, it's a problem with your view.

Comment: Does `select a, b, c from xxx, yyy;` by itself work OK?

Comment: you sure you want a cross join like that? from xxx,yyy. One other thing: when you select columns from joins, specify from with table the column comes from. ex: select xxx.a, yyy.b ......

Answer (score 0):

According to Structure Query Language,view creation should be defined with columns and make sure which columns from it's table.

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW finalview (a,b,c) AS SELECT x.a,x.b,y.c FROM xxx x, yyy y;

First,make sure your view is created or not by  using describtion keyword.
 DESCRIBE finalview;